# Unable to open file mnist.h5

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am working on a project that detects handwritten characters. There are many packages I have imported. One of the package  `keras.models.load_model(mnist.h5)` is throwing following error:

OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'mnist.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Code Snippet is:

```
   from keras.models import load_model
   from tkinter import *
   import tkinter as tk
   import win32gui
   from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
   import numpy as np
   model = load_model('mnist.h5')
```

Using Python 3.7

Can anyone please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Look on your hard disk. Is there a file named "mnist.h5"? Likely not. Also, how does `load_model`work at all? I can't see Keras being imported

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWeller. I am a newbie to Python. So now I have to add a path to this file in my hardware isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer working code to import the Mnist data set.

```
# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
print(tf.__version__)

#### Import the Fashion MNIST dataset
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```